# Array value only returning first character and extra values

Tags: php, arrays, session, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to display pizza toppings in a cart.
I've stored the pizzas and toppings as a multi-dimensional array, this part is fine, here is an example of 1 item with 2 toppings using print_r()

```
Array ( [Special Pizza2] => Array ( [id] => 22 [name] => Special Pizza [quantity] => 1 [des] => [top1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [des] => Beef [qty] => 1 ) [top2] => Array ( [id] => 2 [des] => Chicken [qty] => 1 ) ) )
```

I've searched online and on SOF but am still left scratching my head.

As you'll see in the main code below I've used print_r() on each topping so I could check the arrays for the 2 toppings and to me they seem to display as I'd expect;

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [des] => Beef [qty] => 1 )
```

AND

```
Array ( [id] => 2 [des] => Chicken [qty] => 1 )
```

**Code:**

```
$cart = $_SESSION["cart"];
$c = 0;
foreach($cart as $value)
    {
        if($c==0){
        echo '<div class="crtitm" style="background-color:#e6e6e6;">';
        $c = 1;
    }else{
        echo '<div class="crtitm">';
        $c = 0;
    }

    echo '<b>' .$value[name]. '</b><br>';
//11 because there are 11 toppings
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 11; $x++) {
        $top = "top".$x;
        $pizza = $value[$top];
print_r($pizza);
        foreach($pizza as $return)
        {
                echo $return[des] .'<br>';
        }
    }
    echo $value[des] .'<br>';

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Now for some reason my code is returning

> > 1
> > B
> > 1

AND

> > 2
> > C
> > 1

So I know that this is returning the "id" of the topping then the first char of "des" and then the "qty".

I want my code to just literally just display "Des" +Line-break and then the next topping and so on

> **for reference, the total output is**;
>
> > Special Pizza
> > Array ( [id] => 1 [des] => Beef [qty] => 1 )
> > 1
> > B
> > 1
> > Array ( [id] => 2 [des] => Chicken [qty] => 1 )
> > 2
> > C
> > 1
>
> **And the output of print_r($cart) returns this**;
>
> > Array ( [Special Pizza2] => Array ( [id] => 22 [name] => Special Pizza [quantity] => 1 [des] => [top1] => Array ( [id] => 1 [des] => Beef [qty] => 1 ) [top2] => Array ( [id] => 2 [des] => Chicken [qty] => 1 ) )

Please tell me where I've gone wrong, appreciate all the help to come!

Comment: use quote-marks -  `$value['name']`, not `$value[name]` - do the same for all other array element references, e.g. `$return['des']`, `$value['des']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need this loop:

```
    foreach($pizza as $return)
    {
            echo $return[des] .'<br>';
    }
```

Here, `$pizza` is actually a topping array for one topping, and you only want the description from it. However, you're looping over every element, and then trying to deference it as an array -- which it's not. So just replace the above code with this:

```
echo $pizza['des'];
```

Note, aways quote array indexes like this: `$pizza['des']`

Don't do this: `$pizza[des]`

Comment: Excellent, you hit the nail on the head!
I've replaced it with the following, removed the extra loop and added an` if qty > 0` so it won't give me line breaks for no reason and displays perfectly, thanks!

`code  $qty = $pizza['qty'];
     if($qty>0){
      echo $pizza['dec'] .'<br>';
     }`

Thanks!!

Comment: No need to assign the extra variable, you can just do: `if ($pizza['qty'] > 0) { echo $pizza['dec'] .'<br>'; }`